# issue returning string location in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write a program that checks a list of names entered by the user to see if the new name entered is part of the list. If it's not part of the list, it should return -1 to the main, and print no names found; if it is part of the list, it should return 0 and print the position of the name.

My issue that I'm having is I'll type a list of names, and then type a name to search, and unless that name is the first name on the list, it says name not found. Also, if you look at the code you'll notice that I'm printing "name found" rather then the string position, and that's simply because I haven't figured out how to do that yet. Help with this dilemma would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAMELENGTH 10
#define MAX_NAMES 5
void initialize(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int Number_entrys,int i);
int search(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH], int Number_entrys);
int main()
{

char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH];
int i, Number_entrys,search_result;
 initialize(names,Number_entrys,i);
 search_result= search(names,Number_entrys);
 if (search_result==-1){
    printf("Found no names.\n");
}else{
 printf("Names found");
 }
getch();
return 0;
}

void initialize(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int Number_entrys,int i)
{

 printf("How many names would you like to enter to the list?\n");
 scanf("%d",&Number_entrys);

 if(Number_entrys>MAX_NAMES){
               printf("Please choose a smaller entry\n");
               }else{
  for (i=0; i<Number_entrys;i++){
 scanf("%s",names[i]);


 }
}   
}

int search(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int Number_entrys)
{
int x;
char new_name[MAX_NAMELENGTH];
printf("Now enter a name in which you would like to search the list for\n");

scanf("%s",new_name);

for(x = 0; x < Number_entrys; x++) 
{
if ( strcmp( new_name, names[x] ) == 0 )
{
    return x;
}

 } 
 return -1;        
}
```

Comment: you should use do-while loop to take Number_entrys for less than maxname...because if 1st time it goes greater than max then you are not asking to take Number_entrys again.

Comment: Good catch, I entered the If statement to make sure that it worked correctly, but forgot to loop it back around to re-ask the question.

Comment: And also Number_entrys is local to initialize function , so when you call the search function the Number_entry you pass is having garbage value...

Comment: made adjustments to main post, and it still crashes when entering a name that doesn't exist in the list

Comment: You are still doing a mistake : you should take Number_entrys input either in main and pass that value to initialize or make Number_entrys global... because when you pass Number_entrys to search it still give you error since Number_entrys is garbage... consider this

Comment: I get what you are saying now. I changed the placement of the Number_entrys input and that fixed the issue. If I wanted to print out the position of the name that was found, would I print out x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it's running , I have just removed `<conio.h>` and `getch()` You can include if your compiler requires it .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_NAMELENGTH 10
#define MAX_NAMES 5
void initialize(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int Number_entrys);
int search(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH], int Number_entrys);
int main()
{



char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH];
int i, Number_entrys,search_result;
do
{
 printf("How many names would you like to enter to the list?\n");
 scanf("%d",&Number_entrys);
}while(Number_entrys > MAX_NAMES);

 initialize(names,Number_entrys);
 search_result= search(names,Number_entrys);
 if (search_result==-1){
    printf("Found no names.\n");
}else{
 printf("Names found");
 }

return 0;
}

void initialize(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int Number_entrys)
{
 int i;
 for (i=0; i<Number_entrys;i++){
 scanf("%s",names[i]);
 }
}




int search(char names[MAX_NAMES][MAX_NAMELENGTH],int Number_entrys)
{
int x;
char new_name[MAX_NAMELENGTH];
printf("Now enter a name in which you would like to search the list for\n");
scanf("%s",new_name);

for(x = 0; x < Number_entrys; x++)
{
if ( strcmp( new_name, names[x] ) == 0 )
{

    return x;
 }

 }
 return -1;
}
```

If agree then accept the answer.. It's working fine on my compiler

Comment: Your getting the accept for sure, simply because you have been very helpful. My compiler requires the `conio.h` and the `getch()` unfortunately. I see the edit you made with the `do while` loop which is what my next course of action was going to be as soon as I figured out this issue. Now all I have to do is get it to print out the position of the name when the name is discovered in the list.

Comment: you can do it easily .. don't ask help for every time if you want to really learn ... just try it yourself, you can do it it's very easy ..just return the index where you found the string..and then print the index

Comment: I'm just trying to learn, things can get overwhelming when you first start out. Nevertheless, I appreciate all your help tonight .

Answer (score 3):

Because you are breaking out of your for-loop early. Here's your code better formatted and easier to read. If the first strcmp fails to return 0, your entire search function aborts and returns -1;

```
for(x = 0; x < Number_entrys; x++)
{
     if ( strcmp( new_name, names[x] ) == 0 )
     {
        return x;
     }
     else
     {
         return -1;   
     }  
}
```

This is what you probably want:

```
for(x = 0; x < Number_entrys; x++)
{
     if ( strcmp( new_name, names[x] ) == 0 )
     {
        return x;
     }
}
return -1;
```

Comment: Aww, and I was just about to submit. This looks great.

Comment: This is what I had originally, but the problem I was having was that if you entered a name that wasn't part of the list, then the program crashes.

Comment: @user1781966 : see my comments on your question .. you have lot many errors

Answer (score 0):

In function search - in for loop - you have written if else block so, when first match is not correct it will go to else part..

Fix can be - allow for loop to execute completely, in that use a flag to decide if match is found or not, if found, store the x

after the loop check the flag and accordingly return x.

Comment: Even no need of flag, you can return directly from IF when match is found.

Comment: And to stop program from crashing, caller of search function should take care of return value from the function.

Comment: I thought thats what I was doing by printing no names found lol. Clearly i am a noob.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for above comment. you are handling that thing. great.

Comment: ohhh, no.. ! it coding ! happy coding !
nothing like you said above ! seriously.

Comment: hhahhah !..that "great" word in the comment !! that was the cause !

Comment: haha I guess I didn't notice the period in between thing and great. ;)